# Prevent JavaScript event firing for certain screen widths

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to prevent an event firing when the screen size is lower than 768px.

As the user clicks on a link, an email signup form should pop up from off-canvas, however on screens 768px and below, the contact form remains static at the bottom of the main contact.

No matter what I've tried I cannot prevent either the event firing, or some other strange behaviour, so there's clearly issues with my code.

I've made a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/samholguin/pen/LjiyD) to show the issue...

**JS**

```
( function($) {

    var config = {};

    config.window = $(window);
    config.wWidth = config.window.width();
    config.wHeight = config.window.height();

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".no-svg img").each(function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace(".svg", ".png");
        });

        resizeWindow();

    });

    $(window).resize(resizeWindow);

    function resizeWindow() {
      config.wWidth = config.window.width();
      config.wHeight = config.window.height();

    if ( !Modernizr.touch && config.wWidth > 768 ) {
        buildCanvas();
      }
    }

    function buildCanvas() {

        var $container = $('.email-signup__wrap'),
            $cHeight = $('.email-signup').outerHeight();

        $('.email-signup__wrap').on('click', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault;

            var $this = $(this);

            $container.toggleClass('active');

            if ($container.hasClass('active')) {

                TweenMax.to($container, 0.4, {
                    ease: Power2.easeOut,
                    css:{
                        overflow: 'visible',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: -$cHeight
                    }
                });

            } else {

                TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                    ease: Power2.easeOut,
                    css:{
                        position: 'relative',
                        top: 0
                    },
                    onComplete: hide
                });

                function hide(){
                    $container.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                }

                $("div.mce_inline_error").remove();
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why dont you create and fire the event manually only after checking the screen size?

Comment: @IazertyuiopI I worked this out eventually. I used event delegation in the end, something that was new to me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569989/javascript-event-still-firing-even-when-class-name-doesnt-exist/24570012?noredirect=1#comment38058613_24570012

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you hook up an event handler to a function that isn't declared yet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".no-svg img").each(function () {
        this.src = this.src.replace(".svg", ".png");
    });

    resizeWindow();

});

$(window).resize(resizeWindow); // This line here

function resizeWindow() {
  config.wWidth = config.window.width();
  config.wHeight = config.window.height();

if ( !Modernizr.touch && config.wWidth > 768 ) {
    buildCanvas();
  }
}
```

Move the marked line in the quoted block to your document-ready-function for starters. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".no-svg img").each(function () {
        this.src = this.src.replace(".svg", ".png");
    });

    $(window).resize(resizeWindow); // This line here
    resizeWindow();
});

function resizeWindow() {
  config.wWidth = config.window.width();
  config.wHeight = config.window.height();

  if (!Modernizr.touch && config.wWidth > 768) {
    buildCanvas();
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer to be more precise. This way, the popout still doesn' happen properly, but the code will react to the window resizing and actually behave differently once the window width is smaller than your threshold.

Comment: Made the amend... the event still fires for smaller screens. I'm at a loss with this one. I've used this technique in the past with much more success

Answer (score 0):

This is so weird. I get a lot of behavior from your codepen.

I commented out:

```
$(window).resize(resizeWindow);
```

And changed

```
$('.email-signup__wrap').on('click', function(e) {
```

to

```
$('.email-signup__title').on('click', function(e) {
```

so that it won't toggle active class on clicks inside the div, and it somehow worked. I'm still trying to figure out why. But if you have no time to spare investigating, try my solution.

Comment: The event is still firing on screens small than 768px I'm afraid