# Javascript event still firing even when class name doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain to me how an event would fire when a class name it's targeting doesn't exist..

**CODE**

```
 (function ($) {

    var config = {};

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var wi = $(window).width();

        if ( wi > 768 ) {
            $('body').addClass('dosomething');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('dosomething');
        }

        $(window).resize(function() {

            var wi = $(window).width();

            console.log(wi);

            if ( wi > 768 ) {
                $('body').addClass('dosomething');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('dosomething');
            }

            var $container = $('.email-signup__wrap'),
            $cHeight = $('.email-signup').outerHeight();

            // $('.dosomething .email-signup__wrap').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(ev) {
            $('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dosomething .email-signup__wrap' , function(ev) {

                var $this = $(this);

                if ( ev.type === 'mouseenter' ) {

                    TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                        ease: Power2.easeOut,
                        css:{
                            overflow: 'visible',
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: -$cHeight
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                        ease: Power2.easeOut,
                        css:{
                            position: 'relative',
                            top: 0
                        },
                        onComplete: hide
                    });

                    function hide(){
                        $container.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    }

                    $("div.mce_inline_error").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });

})( jQuery );
```

I've gone a little overboard adding the dosomething class to every selector to try prevent the event from firing on screen sizes below 768px.

Basically the user hovers over a footer bar and a contact form pops up from off canvas, however on smaller screens/mobile, it remains static at the base of the page content.

I know this is rudimentary code, however, I've been trying to get this working for days and I'm rushing bits of code to try find a solution.

I'm not after work arounds, media queries etc.... I really want to understand this for my own sanity.

**FINAL WORKING SOLUTION**

```
  (function ($) {

        var config = {};

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(window).on("resize", function () {
                resizeWindow();
            }).trigger("resize");

            var $container = $('.email-signup__wrap'),
                $cHeight = $('.email-signup').outerHeight();

            $(document).on({
                mouseenter: function() {
                    TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                        ease: Power2.easeOut,
                        css:{
                            overflow: 'visible',
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: -$cHeight
                        }
                    });
                },
                mouseleave: function() {
                    TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                        ease: Power2.easeOut,
                        css:{
                            position: 'relative',
                            top: 0
                        },
                        onComplete: hide
                    });

                    function hide(){
                        $container.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    }

                    $("div.mce_inline_error").remove();
                }
            }, ".dosomething .email-signup__wrap");
        });

        function resizeWindow() {
            config.wWidth = $(window).width();

            if ( config.wWidth > 768 ) {
                $('body').addClass('dosomething');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('dosomething');
            }
        }

    })( jQuery );
```

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready(function () {` because `(function ($) {` is same.

Comment: @C-link No it isn't. `$(function() {` would be the same.

Comment: (function ($) { that is closure in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event delegation` in jquery. you dynamically add the class `.dosomething`

```
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dosomething .email-signup__wrap' , function(ev) {
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little for me to understand please Sudharsan

Comment: you added and remove the class doSomething . and you also write the event for mouseenter mouseleave for same class . so the script checking all the time class is present or not. but event delegation makes it travel up to the document to search the class and get it

Comment: starting to understand. I've edited my code above. The event is now not firing at all, any ideas?